# How to model bind from view to controller via nested view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, model-binding

i cant seem to pass the employee id value from a check box in the Employees.cshtml view to the Delete Post action method. The delete action method returns Delete.cshtml view which renders the Employees.cshtml as that is in an EditorTemplates folder under the Shared folder. When I click submit i cannot seem to pass the IEnumerable of checked @Model.Ids.

What I want to do is delete every entry that has been checked where the checked value is derived in the Employees.cshtml.

Obviously the issue is that the model binding (I think) will be done from the button submit from the Delete.cshtml page, how can I change this?

The Delete action method.

```
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Delete()
    {
        return View(db2.Employees.ToList());
    }
```

The Delete Post action method.

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Delete(IEnumerable<int> EmployeeIDToDelete)
    {
        if (EmployeeIDToDelete != null)
        {
            var employeesToDelete = db2.Employees.Where(x => EmployeeIDToDelete.Contains(x.Id)).ToList();

            foreach (var item in employeesToDelete)
            {
                db2.Employees.Remove(item);
            }
            db2.SaveChanges();
            RedirectToAction("Delete");
        }
        return View(db2.Employees.ToList());
    }
```

My Delete view

```
@model IEnumerable<MVC_Example2___ADO.Models.Employees>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Delete";
}
<html>
<body>
    @using (Html.BeginForm())
    {
        <table align="center">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <td>Check</td>
                    <td>Photo</td>
                    <td>Name</td>
                    <td>Gender</td>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                @Html.EditorForModel()
            </tbody>
        </table>
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Delete Entries" />
    }
</body>
</html>
```

My Employees View

```
@model MVC_Example2___ADO.Models.Employees

<tr>
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="employeeIdsToDelete" id="employeeIdsToDelete" value="@Model.Id" /></td>
    <td>@Html.Image(@Model.Photo, @Model.AlternateText, 125, 130)</td>
    <td>@Model.FullName</td>
    <td>@Model.Gender</td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have named your checkboxes `name="employeeIdsToDelete"` but the parameter of your POST method is `IEnumerable<int> EmployeeIDToDelete` (not plural). The names must match.

Note also you should remove `id="employeeIdsToDelete"` from the input since this is generating duplicate `id` attributes which is invalid html.

Comment: Since the parameter on the controller action is an IEnumerable, I believe he also needs indexes on his name attributes.

Comment: @Tobias, Its not necessary for value types. The `DefaultModelBinder` will still bind it. But as always the preferred approach is a view model with a `bool IsSelected` property and use of `@CheckBoxFor(m => m.IsSelected)`